# The push notification format of Pushwoosh and Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, pushwoosh

Now the pushwoosh works without problem. I can see the notification on the upper left corner of the Android phone. How can I set the notification to be pop-up onto screen rather than the notification on upper left only, even the phone is in silence mode!

Which way should I go for the customization? Thx

```
function pwCall( $action, $data = array() ) {        
$url = 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/' . $action;        
$json = json_encode( array( 'request' => $data ) );        
$res = doPostRequest( $url, $json, 'Content-Type: application/json' );        
print_r( @json_decode( $res, true ) );    }     
pwCall( 'createMessage', array(        '
application' => PW_APPLICATION,        
'auth' => PW_AUTH,        
'notifications' => array(                    
array(                        
'send_date' => 'now',                        
'content' => 'test',                        
'ios_badges' => 3,                        
'data' => array( 'custom' => 'json data' ),                        
'link' => 'http://pushwoosh.com/'                    
)                
)            
)        
);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you handle the Notification ?

Comment: I used the standard API now - http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/

Comment: I using PHP at this moment.

Comment: Show your codes please. (from Hong Kong?)

Answer (score 0):

To configure how to display the incoming push notification, you should write your own logic in the receiver in Android app, as specified in this [page](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-push-notification-sdk-configuration-guide/).

Currently, the tutorial currently uses the following the show the message:

```
private void showMessage(String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Try to create your own logic (user interface, popup method & timing, etc) in the function.